# How can I choose two different rows having some common value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to show path from sql table by selecting rows and showing on web page

Table:

```
**UCId  UCPre                         UCPost                        UCNext  Prob** 
UC01    User must be Registerd        User is Loggined sucessfully  UC02    0.5
UC01    User must be Registerd        User is Loggined sucessfully  UC05    0.5
UC02    User is Loggined sucessfully  User is added                 UC03    1
UC03    User is added                 File is added                 NULL    1
UC04    File is selected              File is deleted               NULL    1
UC05    User is Loggined sucessfully  User is deleted               NULL    1
```

I am using following query

```
select distinct UCId,UCNext,Prob from test  where UCNext <>'Null'
```

Result of Query:

```
UCId    UCNext  Prob
UC01    UC02    0.5
UC01    UC05    0.5
UC02    UC03    1
```

**Q1:** Now I want to select UC01 but there are two rows start with UC01 how can I select row randomly ?
**Q2:** If row number 1 is selected which UC01 as Id and UC02 as UCNext as we can see in the table the UC02 has also UC03 so I want to show complete path which will be

UC01-UC02-UC03

Please  help?

Comment: Do you store the character value 'Null' for NULL values? It's good programming practice to do IS NOT NULL, if only non-nulls are wanted.

Comment: thanks I will do it but kindly dear tell to solve the above question

Comment: Help me understand the logic here - why there are two rows for UC01 with different UCNext values? How can you tell the correct patch what you listed rather than UC01-UC05?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select one random row per `UCid` "partition" using:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  row_number() over (
                    partition by UCid
                    order by newid()) as rn
        ,       *
        from    YourTable
        ) sub1
where   rn = 1 -- Random row per UCid
```

Calculating a "path" is not easy in SQL.  One approach is a recursive CTE.  The top part looks for the roots.  The `union all` separates the top and recursive parts of the CTE.  The recursive part iterates to the children until it reaches the leaf nodes.

```
; with  path as
        (
        select  UCId
        ,       UCNext
        ,       Prob
        ,       cast(UCId as varchar(max)) as path
        ,       UCNext as child_next
        from    dist_rows
        union all
        select  parent.UCId
        ,       parent.UCNext
        ,       parent.Prob
        ,       parent.path + '/' + child.UCid
        ,       child.UCNext
        from    path parent
        join    dist_rows child
        on      child.UCid = parent.child_next
        )
```

Combining the two, you get:

```
; with  dist_rows as
        (
        select  *
        from    (
                select  row_number() over (
                            partition by UCid
                            order by newid()) as rn
                ,       *
                from    YourTable
                ) sub1
        where   rn = 1 -- Random row per UCid
        )
,       path as
        (
        select  UCId
        ,       UCNext
        ,       Prob
        ,       cast(UCId as varchar(max)) as path
        ,       UCNext as child_next
        from    dist_rows
        union all
        select  parent.UCId
        ,       parent.UCNext
        ,       parent.Prob
        ,       parent.path + '/' + child.UCid
        ,       child.UCNext
        from    path parent
        join    dist_rows child
        on      child.UCid = parent.child_next
        )
select  UCId
,       UCNext
,       Prob
,       path
from    path
where   child_next is null -- Only leafs
;
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/13c5a/1/0)  Note that since the rows are randomly chosen, you can get a different path for every execution.